# Google Places API and Wild Card Search Query

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to use wild card search using the [Google Places Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) (i.e. Nik matching Nike Store)?

I realize Google also provides a [Google Places Autocomplete API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete.html) however I can't use it because of the  limitation that type  can only be set to `establishment` or `geocode` (not values such as `shoe_store`, `jewelry_store` or `clothing_store` that I need).

Comment: Any luck finding an answer to this elsewhere Kevin?

Comment: @Matt Sorry, no. The question was asked so long ago now I don't really remember anything about it!